# Automating Azure Recovery Services without DPM

Tags: azure, recovery-services

I'm trying to push out Azure Recovery Services to users desktops without having to manually go to all the users desktops to configure the Azure Recovery Agent and the Vault Credentials.  All the automation options that I'm finding assume that you have DPM in place (which we don't, and it isn't required for file/folder backups which is all we care about for this project).

Has anyone seen a way to configure Azure Recovery Services on a users desktop/laptop via powershell, command line switches, witch craft without needing a DPM server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Backup Server will be a better option because managing all these backups without a centralized solution could be very hard depending on your inventory size. It is exactly the same as DPM, but free. The only difference from DPM is that it does not allow you to backup to tape, instead, you have to use azure cloud storage.

The only downside is the need of a Windows Server for installation:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-microsoft-azure-backup

If you really want to use the stand-alone Azure Backup Agent, you can use powershell and active directory to automate the installation. You can find all the necessary cmdlets below:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-client-automation